# Checking a character from a keypress without halting the program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char stop;

    cout << "Press X to Stop Alarm" << endl;

    while(stop != 'x' ){
        Beep(523, 500);
        cin >> stop;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above is a small piece of code to use as an example.

Within the while loop the machine beeps and then prompts the user for the key press that will end the loop, and if incorrect beeps again.

However with this method the program halts waiting for the user to enter a character which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

I'd like the loop to check if a key press has occurred and if not ignore waiting for one and execute the loop again.

Comment: You should tag the question as windows if you only want a windows solution. General C++ solution would be much harder if ever possible because C++ does not explicitely manage low level IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header file `<conio.h>` contains two functions you may be interested in:

```
_kbhit()    // Was a key pressed?
_getch()    // Which key was pressed?
```